# jQuery ajax doesn't work with last version of chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, jquery

Hey guys,
I have a little problem with a simple ajax request. I can't figure it out why jquery ajax method doesn't work with the last version of chrome ... on ff work great so as on opera but on chrome i don't get any response and no errors. This is my js code:

```
function load(idno){
    var url = 'index.php';
    $.get(
        url,
        {
            pagina:"ajax",
            show:"cars",
            brand:idno
        },
        function(data) { document.getElementById("model").innerHTML=data },
        "html"
    );
}
```

Comment: What is `data`? What doctype? What is `idno`? Are there duplicate `model` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long long nith I've managed to resolve the problem. My JS code is good and maybe Phil's too ... I didn't try that in this version but the real problem in Chrome is that onclick attributes on option tags aren't allowed. So I made the event

```
<select onchange='loadData(this.value,'models')'></select>
```

and it is working great. Thank you Phil anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Any reason you're not just using `jQuery.load()`? Eg

```
$('#model').load('index.php', {
    pagina: 'ajax',
    show: 'cars',
    brand: idno
});
```

At a guess, I'd say the problem is with the `innerHTML` call. A more robust method would be to use `jQuery.html()`, eg

```
function(data) { $('#model').html(data); }
```

**Edit**

Just whipped up this test and it works fine

```
<?php
// test.php
echo '<pre>', print_r($_REQUEST, true), '</pre>';
```

---

```
<!-- test.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="model">
          Default text
      </div>
      <p><button id="fetch-data">Fetch Data</button></p>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(function($) {
              $('#fetch-data').click(function() {
                  $('#model').load('test.php', {
                      pagina: 'ajax',
                      show: 'cars',
                      brand: 123
                  });
                  return false;
              });
          });
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click the button, I can see all the request variables sent to the script

Comment: ah ... and $('#model').load('index.php', {
    pagina: 'ajax',
    show: 'cars',
    brand: idno
}); isn't working cause the request is made without parameters

Comment: @Badea I've added a working example to my answer. Tested in Chrome 9.0.597.94

Comment: i've tried your example and it work on google chrome but there is a problem: on chrome the default method is POST and on ff is GET. Anyway I've made some adjustments in my php program to deal with this but after that I've tried to put $('#model').load('test.php', {
                      pagina: 'ajax',
                      show: 'cars',
                      brand: 123
                  }); in my function because I have a select box with car brands and when you click a options fills another select box with models of cars from that brand.Still not working ... same problem ... no error

Answer (score 0):

because of Security reason chrome not allow cross-domain communication if request is not from a trusted sites,
if you want to use $.ajax in chrome so you need to disbale web security of chrome
use this comman.

```
your_chrome_path --disable-web-security
```

after doing this $.ajax works fine.